# Dynamic Pivot Table to join with other table

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

I have a the following data in an mssql table

```
select ID,Date,Amount from r.payment_planning 
where Date>=convert(datetime,convert(varchar,getdate(),111))
```

```
ID      Date         Amount
720     2024-01-11   10105.00
506     2024-01-11   20000.00
18      2024-01-11   19486.00
1195    2024-01-12   4239.00
```

After using dynamic pivot the result from the query

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max), @query as nvarchar(max)

set @cols = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(convert(varchar,C.Date,111)) from  r.payment_planning c 
where c.Date>=convert(datetime,convert(varchar,getdate(),111))
for xml path (''),type ).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')

set @query = '
select ID,'+ @cols + 'from 
               (select ID,Date,Amount from r.payment_planning) x
               pivot 
               (max(Amount) for Date in (' + @cols + ') 
               ) p'

execute(@query)
```

is as follows

```
ID      2024/01/11      2024/01/12
18      19486.00        NULL
506     20000.00        NULL
720     10105.00        NULL
1195    NULL            4239.00
```

I want to use the dynamic result in a query to join with other tables. What is the best way of getting this data as a table.

I am not being able to return this data as a table. I would like to use this table with other tables to create an integrated result.

Comment: Why can't you join that query to table? What programming language are you comfortable with?